# Displaying an XML document in Yii

Tags: xml, yii

I would like to known if it is possible to display an XML document using Yii. I don't want to create the document in the code, it already exists. I just want to show it in the browser kind of like a normal view, except instead of a webpage the XML document should be rendered. The XML document will be shown, for instance, at the press of a button.
I hope this question makes sense..

Comment: There is no Yii specific way to do this as far as I know, it's just dealing with PHP and HTML.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If what you want to do is return a XML document instead of an HTML document (like for a REST API or something), just create a new 'xml.php' layout that has the base XML, something like `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes">`, and in your action before you render the view, set the HTTP header like so:

```
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
```

There are more helpful hints here in this [Yii REST how-to article](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/175/how-to-create-a-rest-api/).

**-OR-**

Assuming you just want to output the XML document with preserved spacing and tag characters for people to read (and example kind of thing), in your view action:

```
<?php
public function actionView()
{
$output = $myXMLString; // I don't know where you are getting your XML from, but this is it
$output = htmlentities($output); // convert HTML/XML tags like < to their HTML codes ($lt;))
  $this->render('view',array(
    'xmlString'=>htmlentities($output), // send it to the view for rendering
  ));
}
```

Then, in your view:

```
<pre>
<?php echo $xmlString ?>
<pre>
```

Wrapping your XML string in `<pre>` tags when echoing should preserve the XML indentation, and encoding it with `htmlentities()` should prevent your `<xmltags>` from being parsed by the browser so they display correctly.

There might be some nice [JavaScript libraries that do XML syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/378205/web-xml-editor-with-xml-syntax-highlighting) highlighting as well.

I hope this answers your question?

Comment: Thanks for the great tips. I'm probably going to use this info at some point, even though I realized that for my original question a simple link to the pre-existing XML document is all I need.